# Internal keyboard not working with Ubuntu 20.04 (same with 22.04 and 23.04) on ASUS Expertbook B1502CBA-BQ0553X

Tags: drivers, kernel, keyboard, asus

Context : Bought a new computer with windows and everything was working fine. (keyboard and all)
I installed ubuntu 22.04 first because I don't want windows but the computer couldn't reboot properly (first problem) and the internal keyboard wasn't working. Then I tried to install 23.04, same problems.
I then tried to install Ubuntu 20.04 and the internal keyboard still isn't working. I'm keeping this version because it's the only one that is able to boot properly.

I tried installing latest linux kernel version but it was no help.

Do you have any idea to fix the keyboard problem and maybe an explanation on why 22.04 and 23.04 are not able to boot ?

Hint : When the computer boots the error : "kernel: tpm tpm0: [Firmware Bug]: TPM interrupt not working, polling instead" is displayed

System info :

```
System:
  Kernel: 5.15.0-86-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A 
  Desktop: Gnome 3.36.9 wm: gnome-shell dm: GDM3 
  Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (Focal Fossa) 

Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: ASUSTeK product: ASUS EXPERTBOOK B1502CBA v: 1.0 
  serial: <filter> 
  Mobo: ASUSTeK model: B1502CBA v: 1.0 serial: <filter> 
  UEFI: American Megatrends LLC. v: B1502CBA.304 date: 04/19/2023 

Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 42.4 Wh condition: 42.4/41.9 Wh (101%) volts: 12.9/11.8 
  model: X421-35 serial: <filter> status: Full 

CPU:
  Topology: 6-Core model: 12th Gen Intel Core i5-1235U bits: 64 type: MT MCP 
  arch: N/A L2 cache: 12.0 MiB 
  flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx 
  bogomips: 59904 
  Speed: 571 MHz min/max: 400/4400 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 452 2: 591 
  3: 696 4: 509 5: 669 6: 595 7: 590 8: 418 9: 800 10: 779 11: 591 12: 685 

Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel vendor: ASUSTeK driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
  chip ID: 8086:4628 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 driver: i915 compositor: gnome-shell 
  resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz, 1920x1080~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel Graphics (ADL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 21.2.6 
  direct render: Yes 

Audio:
  Device-1: Intel vendor: ASUSTeK driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 
  bus ID: 00:1f.3 chip ID: 8086:51c8 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.15.0-86-generic 

Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 476.94 GiB used: 20.23 GiB (4.2%) 
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Micron model: 2400 MTFDKBA512QFM 
  size: 476.94 GiB speed: 63.2 Gb/s lanes: 4 serial: <filter> 

Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 281.77 GiB used: 20.22 GiB (7.2%) fs: ext4 
  dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2 

Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 45.0 C mobo: 27.8 C 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 

Info:
  Processes: 321 Uptime: 1h 58m Memory: 15.24 GiB used: 2.07 GiB (13.6%) 
  Init: systemd v: 245 runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 9.4.0 alt: 9 
Shell: bash 
  v: 5.0.17 running in: gnome-terminal inxi: 3.0.38
```

Comment: Please attach more system info: `sudo apt install inxi` and then `inxi -Fxxzc0` in terminal

Comment: @RA post updated !